Use Keycloak OTP for Federated Users
I have already implemented the User Storage SPI to authenticate the users present in my external DB. Now, I want to use the TOTP authentication for the same users. I tried to setup 2FA using QR Code provided in Keycloak’s Authenticator tab and I can see the record in fed_user_credential table as well but that record does not appear in the Authenticator tab and the whole behaviour is very strange.
Below is the code of supportsCredentialType method present in UserStorageProvider SPI
@Override
public boolean supportsCredentialType(String credentialType) {
return PasswordCredentialModel.TYPE.endsWith(credentialType) || OTPCredentialModel.TYPE.equals(credentialType);
}

Can you please guide how to use Keycloak 2FA with users present in external DB which are federated users?
